# Retriving all records but still showing error in console

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

I'm just creating a simple servlet and retrieve records from a database using mysqldb. I also provided jars `"mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"`

But it's going to retrieved all records and try block executed without any error(no any SOP executed of catch block). But still it's showing the error described below. Somewhere I read put 
`asm-all 3.3.1.jar cglib-nodep 2.1.3.jar`. But not any effect

```
package com.sapphire.jdbcsql;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControllerServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/ControllerServlet")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public ControllerServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Connection conn=null;
        Statement Stat=null;
        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
            Stat=conn.createStatement();


            ResultSet rs=Stat.executeQuery("select * from chatbox");
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("a error started");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("b error ended");
        }


    }

}
```

I got the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:717)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:112)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:268)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4656)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    ... 30 more

Jul 12, 2014 10:08:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 12, 2014 10:08:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 12, 2014 10:08:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5588 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with retrieving all records, because your problem happens much before that.

You have a struts2 application using opensymphony and you do not have a correct deployment for those packages so you get this error.   You need to revisit the documentation for opensymphony and ensure that you have followed the documentation correctly so you can create a "Hello World" `@WebServlet`.

Then, and not before then, you can look into this code again.

Answer (score 1):

As the stacktrace says `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor` that means you dont have the asm-commons jar in your classpath

Just provide asm-commons.jar to the classpath, Get it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadasmcommonsjar.htm)

Comment: i insert asm-commons-3.3.jar in lib folder but still same error :(

Comment: if it is eclipse then right click on the jar in the lib and add it to build path

Comment: i removed asm-commons.jar from lib as well as class path. and again clean webserver and redeploy the project but no error :( . can you explain plz why ?

Comment: thats hard to say from here may be you are already having the jar in the classpath